# Symfony2 SyliusShippingBundle errors when installing. Is it still working?

Tags: symfony, sylius

I need to get a few ecommerce components from bundles. So I found Sylius E-Commerce bundle. And I want to install the Shipping Bundle.
http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusShippingBundle/index.html

However at the last part, when I need to update my schema I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Sylius\Component\Translation\Model\AbstractTranslatable' not found in C:\wamp\www\karpedealb2c\vendor\sylius\shipping\Model\ShippingMethod.php on line 24
```

So I go to the Sylius vendor and I can see that the class AbstractTranslatable doesnt exist.. I did some research and I found that these models are a part of a SyliusTranslationBundle that doesnt even exist anymore...

Do these bundles even work? Its not the first time I cant install Sylius Bundles.

P.S Are there any other good bundles that offer different e-commerce models and etc?

**UPDATE**

If I try to add them seperately:

```
    "sylius/translation-bundle": "^0.15.0",
    "sylius/shipping-bundle": "^0.15.0",
    "sylius/resource-bundle": "0.16.*
```

I get these errors hen updating composer:

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested package sylius/resource-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for sylius/translation-bundle ^0.15.0 -> satisfiable by sylius/translation-bundle[v0.15.0].
    - sylius/translation-bundle v0.15.0 requires sylius/resource-bundle 0.15.*@dev -> no matching package found.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for sylius/shipping-bundle ^0.15.0 -> satisfiable by sylius/shipping-bundle[v0.15.0].
    - sylius/shipping-bundle v0.15.0 requires sylius/resource-bundle 0.15.*@dev -> no matching package found.
```

Comment: Which version of the bundle are you using?

Comment: the version that it install by the documentation: 0.15.0

Comment: Did you add SyliusResourceBundle and its dependencies ?

Comment: Yes I did. Doing: php composer.phar require "sylius/shipping-bundle". Installs both the shipping and resource bundle and a couple more.

Comment: It looks like you are missing the `sylius/translation-bundle`. Add it to your `composer.json` and it should work.

Comment: I updated my post please check it